IDEAFilter R package not working under reactive expression
I am trying to upload a file using fileInput() function and use the R package IDEAFilter to filter it and show the filtered data. But it seems that I can not filter a reactive expression using IDEAFilter package. I am not sure if that's true or my code is wrong.
Here is my code:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(IDEAFilter)
library(dplyr)

ui <- page_fixed(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
    IDEAFilter_ui("data_filter"),
    verbatimTextOutput("file1_contents"),
    tableOutput("contents"),
    tableOutput("contents1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$file1_contents <- renderPrint({print(input$file1)})
    
    output$contents <- renderTable({
        file <- input$file1
        req(file)
        ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
        validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
        a<- read.csv(file$datapath)
        a
    })

    filtered_data<-reactive({
        file <- input$file1
        req(file)
        ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
        validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
        a<- read.csv(file$datapath)
        IDEAFilter("data_filter", data =a,verbose = FALSE)
    })

    output$contents1 <- renderTable({
        filtered_data()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

I tried to upload data and filter it using IDEAFilter package.
It seems that IDEAFilter package  is not working with reactive data. If I use the package with data uploaded from the computer it works, but not with reactive data.

Similar issue seen there Github Biogen-Inc: IDEAFilter cannot handle reactive file uploads in Shiny #32. Closed yesterday by an other  solution simpler than mine below. :)

Explanations
When we are looking at the source of IDEAFilter::IDEAFilter(), typing IDEAFilter::IDEAFilter without parenthesis, we can see that IDEAFilter is a shiny moduleServer():
IDEAFilter::IDEAFilter
function (id, data, ..., col_subset = NULL, preselection = NULL, 
    verbose = FALSE) 
{
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
       ns <- session$ns
       ...
       observeEvent(...
       ...etc...
    } end of moduleServer
} end of function

Therefore we have to use it inside a scope of a data if we want to get the data.
server <- function(input, output) {

  react <- reactiveValues(
    filtered_data_idea =NULL
  )

  ...

  observeEvent(filtered_data.react(),{
    
    req(filtered_data.react())  
    
    react$filtered_data_idea <- IDEAFilter("data_filter", data = filtered_data.react(), verbose = FALSE)
    
  })

  ...

  output$contents1 <- renderTable({
    if (shiny::is.reactive(react$filtered_data_idea)) {
      react$filtered_data_idea()
    } else NULL
    
  })
}

IDEAFilter
I didn't kown IDEAFilter, thanks :)

https://github.com/Biogen-Inc/IDEAFilter

Here is all of the source:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(IDEAFilter)
library(dplyr)

ui <- page_fixed(
  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
  IDEAFilter_ui("data_filter"),
  verbatimTextOutput("file1_contents"),
  h3("contents filtered by IDEAFilter"),
  tableOutput("contents1"),
  h3("all the contents"),
  tableOutput("contents"),
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  react <- reactiveValues(
    filtered_data_idea =NULL
  )
  
  output$file1_contents <- renderPrint({print(input$file1)})
  
  filtered_data.react<-reactive({
    file <- input$file1
    req(file)
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    a<- read.csv(file$datapath)
    a
    
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(filtered_data.react(),{
    
    req(filtered_data.react())  
    
    react$filtered_data_idea <- IDEAFilter("data_filter", data = filtered_data.react(), verbose = FALSE)
    
  })
  
  
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    datas <- filtered_data.react()
    
    if (nrow(datas)) (datas)
    else NULL
    
  })
  
  
  output$contents1 <- renderTable({
    if (shiny::is.reactive(react$filtered_data_idea)) {
      react$filtered_data_idea()
    } else NULL
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

